# How to make Iterate all 2d array with binary array value - python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops

what i want :

iterate 1 :

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

iterate 2 :

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

iterate 2 :

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

iterate -1(Last iterate):

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: 1) Just to be clear, these are `list`s, *not* arrays.  (Technically very different things)  2) What code have you written to resolve this on your own, with your research?  Where *exactly* are you having an issue?

Comment: I'm very new to this, I haven't tried to code it because I don't know how to make/start it

Comment: Tip: If using core Python, this can be accomplished using a simple set of nested `for` loops.  Please read the ‘how to ask’ section, as it explains that while we are happy to help, we are not a coding service and expect a genuine effort on your part both in *research* and a code attempt. Unfortunately “I’m new …” doesn’t get you off the hook.  Trust me, in the research and trying to figure it out, you’ll learn *a lot*.  Start with the tip above and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think like this :

```
import itertools
n = 2

list_of_solution = []
for i in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n*n):
    sol= [list(i)[x:x+n] for x in range(0, len(list(i)), n)]
    list_of_solution.append(sol)

print(list_of_solution)
```

Result

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], 
[[0, 0], [0, 1]], 
[[0, 0], [1, 0]], 
...
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]]
```